# How to close infowindow

Tags: android, google-maps

How to implement close infowindow when click the 'x' in infowindow ?
I'm using infowindowadapter google maps android. 
just like the picture in below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10hvL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GoogleMap.setOnWindowCloseListener()`.

Next time, you should try find out by yourself first, rather than just quickly post a question here.